# C++ array, counting repeats in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, search, count

I've been learning c++ recently (coming from java) and I am attempting to count the number of repeating values in an array. For some reason the array is not being properly passed to my counter function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


//quicksort for int arrays, left should be left index (0), right is right index(last one)
void quSort(int input[], int left, int right);

//binary search will return the index of the target or -1 if not found
int biSearch(int input[], int target, int iLeft, int iRight);

//count reapeats in the array with biSearch
int countRepeats(int input[], int target);

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int) time(0));
    int test[1000];

    //generate 100 random numbers under 1000
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        test[i] = rand()%1000;

    //output test original
    cout << "orig: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test); i++)
    {
        cout << test[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    //sorting
    quSort(test,0,( (sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test))-1));

    cout << "sorted: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test); i++)
    {
        cout << test[i] << " ";
    }

    //binary search test
    int target;
    int iTarget;

    cout << "\nenter target: ";
    cin >> target;

    iTarget = biSearch(test,target,0,sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test));

    cout << "\n the target is at index: " << iTarget << " :: test[" << iTarget << "] = " << test[iTarget];

    //count repeats

    cout << "\nWith " << countRepeats(test,target) << " repeats";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


//quicksort function; effiecent array sorter; important for furture array analysis!!!
void quSort(int input[], int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = input[(left+right)/2];
    int l = left;//to control loop
    int r = right;

    while(l <= r)//will get smaller over iterations
    {   
        int placeHold;// for use in swap, temp number

        //finds value higher than the pivot from left
        while(input[l] < pivot)
            l++;
        //find value lower than pivot on right
        while(input[r] > pivot)
            r--;
        //swapper
        if(l <= r)
        {
        //if the value greater than pivot is to the left of the value
        //lessser than pivot
            placeHold = input[l];
            input[l] = input[r];
            input[r] = placeHold;

            l++;
            r--;

        }
        //recursion to sort whole array until l=r
        if(left<r)
            quSort(input, left, r);
        if(l < right)
            quSort(input, l , right);
    }
}

//binary search function; array MUST be sorted
int biSearch(int input[], int target, int iLeft, int iRight)
{
    if(iLeft > iRight)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int iMid = ((iLeft+iRight)/2);

        if(input[iMid] > target)
            return biSearch(input, target, iLeft, iMid-1);
        else if(input[iMid] < target)
            return biSearch(input, target, iMid+1, iRight);
        else
            return iMid;//target found
    }
}


//Must be sorted
int countRepeats(int *input, int target)
{
    int holder[sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input)];
    int biSResult;
    int counter = 0;

    biSResult = biSearch(input,target,0,sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input));

    //bug test
    cout<<"c++" << biSResult << "c++";
    //

    while(biSResult != -1)
    {
        holder[biSResult] = target;

        counter++;

        input[biSResult] = 0;
        quSort(input,0,( (sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input))-1));
        biSResult = biSearch(input,target,0,sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input));
    }

    biSResult = biSearch(holder,target,0,sizeof(holder)/sizeof(*holder));

    while(biSResult != -1)
    {

        input[biSResult] = target;

        holder[biSResult] = 0;
        quSort(holder,0,( (sizeof(holder)/sizeof(*holder))-1));
        biSResult = biSearch(input,target,0,sizeof(holder)/sizeof(*holder));
    }
    return counter;
}
```

If anyone knows why this is happening it would be a great help

Comment: Please don't post hundreds of lines of code that requires us to hunt down the issue.  Instead, reduce this to a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) instead of a wall of code.

Comment: I realize this isn't what you want to hear, but at least in the future you should really, really, really consider using `std::array` or better yet `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. You wouldn't have any problem passing a `std::vector` to a function as a const reference for your counting function

Comment: You may use `std::vector`, `std::sort` and `std::equal_range`.

Comment: `I am attempting to count the number of repeating values in an array` This can be accomplished in less than 10 lines of code using a `std::map<int,int>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in `countRepeats()`:

(1) as already mentionned in other answers, there is an error in the way parameters are passed.  There is no way to calculate the size of the array in the function whether you use `int*` or `int[]`.   So best pass arguments to this function as you do in `quSort()` by giving not only the array address but also a start and an end counter.

(2) your programme will crash if the user would asks for a target of 0 :  your `while(biSResult != -1)` would loop for ever.

(3) this function sorts again and again the array. This seems to be pretty bad for performance.  Why don't you make use of the fact that the array is already sorted ?  You could start counting from the found index .  Just think that you'd have to count before and after this position, because you're not sure that iTarget is the very first occurence.  This could look like:

```
int countRepeats(int input[], int pos, int start, int end )
{
    if (pos<start || pos>=end)  // you never know ! 
        return 0; 

    int counter = 1;

    for (int i=pos-1; i>=start && input[i]==input[pos]; i--)
        counter++; 
    for (int i=pos+1; i<end && input[i]==input[pos]; i++)
        counter++;

    return counter;
}
```

By the way, I've tested it and it works.  You just have to adapt the prototype and call it in your main function with

```
   cout << "\nWith " << countRepeats(test, iTarget, 0,
                    sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test) ) << " repeats";
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of function countRepeats declared as

```
int countRepeats(int *input, int target)
```

that is it has type `int *`

So

```
sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input)
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof( int * )/sizeof( int )
```

If for example sizeof( int * ) is equal to 4 and sizeof( int ) also is equal to 4 then the expression will be equal to 1. That is the value of the expression does not depend on how many elements the array that was passed to the function as argument has.

You should pass the size of the array explicitly as an argument of the function. So th function should be declared as

```
int countRepeats(int *input, int n, int target);
```

Or you could declare the first parameter of the function as a reference to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate the size of an array inside a function that received a pointer to the array. This is because the value of `sizeof(input)` inside your counting function is just going to return the size of a pointer to an int. So `sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input)` will always be 1.

If you instead calculate the size of the array and store it as an `int` in main, then pass that to your counting function it should work. So changing your counting function call to:

`cout << "\nWith " << countRepeats(test,target,sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test)) << " repeats";`

And your `countRepeats` declaration to:

`int countRepeats(int input[], int target, int size);`

Then inside your `countRepeats` definition, everywhere you had `(sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input))` you can just say `size`:

```
int countRepeats(int *input, int target, int size)
{
    int holder[size];
    int biSResult;
    int counter = 0;

    biSResult = biSearch(input,target,0,size);

    //bug test
    cout<<"c++" << biSResult << "c++";
    //

    while(biSResult != -1)
    {
        holder[biSResult] = target;

        counter++;

        input[biSResult] = 0;
        quSort(input,0,(size-1));
        biSResult = biSearch(input,target,0,size);
    }

    biSResult = biSearch(holder,target,0,size);

    while(biSResult != -1)
    {

        input[biSResult] = target;

        holder[biSResult] = 0;
        quSort(holder,0,(size-1));
        biSResult = biSearch(input,target,0,size);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

But you should really just use `std::vector` instead. Could have had `std::vector<int> test (1000);` and since your `countRepeats` changes your array through calls to `quSort` you can pass the vector as a reference (just as efficient as passing a pointer, allows changes to affect the original): `int countRepeats(std::vector<int>&, int target);` and you can always find its size by `test.size()`